# Where should I post product development/release questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm pretty sure product development or release questions aren't allowed on Stack Overflow, if I understood correctly. But I was wondering, where could I ask a question and get an appropriate answer with subject matter pertaining to the production and release of projects, and moving a project through the production stages?

Comment: What kind of questions? Can you make an example?

Comment: Can't say for sure, as that's fairly broad, but sounds like [programmers.se] - ["Everything that can be considered part of the SDLC, except implementation."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)